# Aggregate sum multidimensional arrays grouped by name

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => test 1
            [capacity] => 180
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 2
            [capacity] => 251
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 2
            [capacity] => 241
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 3
            [capacity] => 554
        )

)
```

I want to sum the "capacity" key value of same "operation_name" key arrays and made it as a one array.

In the above array I need to sum the following 2 arrays,

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 2
            [capacity] => 251
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 2
            [capacity] => 241
        )
```

And output the resulting array as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => test 1
            [capacity] => 180
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 2
            [capacity] => 492
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 3
            [capacity] => 554
        )

)
```

How to do this with php?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to use foreach and loop through, but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Post the code, let's see if we can improve it (hurry, before your question gets closed).

Comment: Look at my answer, it should be what you are looking for.

Comment: loop over the array. create a new array with operation as the key. if the operation key doesn't exist, add it. If it does exist, add the capacity together. use array_values on the new array to reset the keys back to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple foreach:

```
<?php    
$arr = Array
(
    Array
        (
            "operation_name" => "test 1",
            "capacity" => 180
        ),

    Array
        (
            "operation_name" => "Operation 2",
            "capacity" => 251
        ),

    Array
        (
            "operation_name" => "Operation 2",
            "capacity" => 241
        ),

    Array
        (
            "operation_name" => "Operation 3",
            "capacity" => 554
        )

);


$tmpArr = [];

//Finding the sum
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $key = $value['operation_name'];
    if(array_key_exists($key, $tmpArr)){   //Check if key exists, if so add otherwise add a new entry
        $tmpArr[$key] += $value['capacity'];
    } else {
        $tmpArr[$key] = $value['capacity'];
    }
}

$finalArr = [];

//Creating desired array
foreach ($tmpArr as $key => $value) {
    $Arr['operation_name'] = $key;
    $Arr['capacity'] = $value;
    $finalArr[] = $Arr;
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => test 1
            [capacity] => 180
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 2
            [capacity] => 492
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [operation_name] => Operation 3
            [capacity] => 554
        )

)
```

---

**One looper:**

```
$finalArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $key = $value['operation_name'];
    if(array_key_exists($key, $finalArr)){
        $finalArr[$key]['capacity'] += $value['capacity'];
    } else {
        $finalArr[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r(array_values($finalArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
 array
    (
        "operation_name" => "test 1",
        "capacity" => 180
    )
,
 array
    (
        "operation_name" => "Operation 2",
        "capacity" => 252
    )
,
 array
    (
        "operation_name" => "Operation 2",
        "capacity" =>241
    )
,
array
    (
        "operation_name" => "Operation 3",
        "capacity" => 554
    )
);
$sum = 0;
$operations = array();
foreach($array as $val){
        if( !isset($operations[$val["operation_name"]] ) ){
                 $operations[$val["operation_name"]] = $val["capacity"];
        } else {
                $operations[$val["operation_name"]] += $val["capacity"];
        }
}
$final = array();
foreach( $operations as $operation => $capacity ) {
        $final[] = array('operation_name' => $operation,
                                'capacity' => $capacity);
}
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering because the existing answers have two loops for some reason:

```
foreach($array as $val){
    if(!isset($total[$val['operation_name']] ) ){
        $total[$val['operation_name']] = $val;
    } else {
        $total[$val['operation_name']]['capacity'] += $val['capacity'];
    }
}
// reindex array
$total = array_values($total);
```